# Unity wall climbing 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made little code for detect climbing (script attached to the player object):

```
private float PlayerColHeight;
private float PlayerColWidth;
private bool Climb = false;


void Start () {
    PlayerCol = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D> ();
    PlayerColHeight = PlayerCol.bounds.size.y;
    PlayerColWidth = PlayerCol.bounds.size.x;
}
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col){
    if (!IsGrounded() && (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")) {
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        Vector2 wallPos = col.transform.position;
        float wallColHeight = col.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().bounds.size.y;
        if ((position.y+PlayerColHeight/2)==(wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2)){
            Climb = true;               
        }
        Debug.Log (Climb);
    }
}
```

This means when player in the air and colliding with wall, i need to check if player top point Y = wall top point Y and understand that it works. 
But this is not works... Console returns only False.
Image:

[image]

Why it doesn't works? If you know another way to make climbing, can you explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your condition statement is wrong

```
    if ((position.y+PlayerColHeight/2)==(wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2)){
    Climb = true;               
}
```

It should be

```
    if ((position.y+PlayerColHeight/2) <= (wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2)){
    Climb = true;               
}
```

Climb was true only when both values were equal but you are interested on climbing when the player position is smaller than the wall, right?

In any case you should check your values debugging the game or just writing logs with the values position.y+PlayerColHeight/2 and wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2 to understand what's going on.

Edit: It could happen that when you are close to get out of the "climbing zone" your player gets stucked as he will get Climb = false, the ideal should be enable climbing when you are in the wall, you don't care if jumping again will leave the player above the wall, what it's more you could be interested on that for reaching the top of the wall in same situations

Comment: No, i need only mine if statement, but now i tried to add System.Math.Round to my player top point determinant and it works...

Comment: Both should work. But "==" on coordinates will almost never work, because of floating point errors. You will compare y=1.00001 against 1 - that would return false.

Comment: I didn't know about that, i just tried to debug my float values of player top point and detected this. Anyway thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

The chances that these variables are **exactly** the same is low. One frame the player will be a bit above, and the next frame a bit below.

The Player should have a range below the wall in which he can climb. Try this:

```
const float climbZoneHeight = 1f; // In world unit, the range of the wall on which the player can climb. Choose a value that works well in your case;

const float distToWallTop = (wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2) - (position.y+PlayerColHeight/2);

if (distToWallTop >= 0 && distToWallTop <= climbZoneHeight )
{
    Climb = true;               
}
```

Comment: Yes, it helps, but i need to detect climb only when Cat collider is lower then wall top point

Comment: I think this should work better than the current accepted answer

Comment: I did this if(((wallPos.y + wallColHeight/2) - (position.y+PlayerColHeight/2))<=climbZone)

Comment: But this will also be true when the player is above the wall. the edit I made to the post should fix that

Comment: Yes, this is what i need. Then climb animation to the wall will be start. You maybe think that my cat will be above the walls? No, only lower for now, i just Whiteboxing my game. Anyway thanks for this kind of help, maybe i'll use it in the future, when another features will be added:)

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, consider the following cases:

1. As already posted in another response, you should not use equality comparison, instead you should make less than comparison, i.e. `player_top_y <= wall_top_y`
2. Secondly, instead of calculating `player_top_y` as `player_y + player_collider_y`, you should directly use the collision [contact point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint.html)